# Android Studio Project works in Emulator but not in Phone (Samsung Galaxy A5)

Tags: android-studio, wamp

I'm facing a problem my project works perfectly in emulator of Android Studio, but I can't say the same about when I test it on the phone (Samsung Galaxy A5).

This is a project for my school. I'm new to this kind of programming.

The application consists in a Login and a Register activity connecting to my localhost using WAMPP, I'm not sure but I think I must add some function or something like it to my Manifests. I think the problem is that the application uses PHP co connect to WAMPP, Maybe I have to install something in my device or change something to my code. I would appreciate all kinds of help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gonalo.demodemo">
/**
* under this line where it says uses-permission ... Internet.. do i must add something else

*/
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What problem are you having on your galaxy?

Comment: @Nicholas , i can not Log In or Register in my application on the device, but it works in my emulator of Android Studio. Im also Connected to the same Wifi with same IP as i defined in Android

Comment: @Nicholas Thank you for trying to know the solution, i have found the problem. I had to Turn off the Firewall of the Windows.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted out. I was just moderating and thought the question could use a little more information.